# Chart.js - moving javascript into application.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am using Chart.js to make a radar graph. I watched the railscast about charts (morris.js) and am simply trying to get the example data to display on the page.

When I put the javascript directly into the html it works:

```
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="450"></canvas>
<script>

  var radarChartData = {
    labels : ["Eating","Drinking","Sleeping","Designing","Coding","Partying","Running"],
    datasets : [
        {
          fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
          strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
          data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
          },
          {
          fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
          strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
          data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
          }
            ]

        }

    var myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData,{scaleShowLabels : false, pointLabelFontSize : 10});

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I try to move the javascript into results.js.coffee (I converted to coffeescript):

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
jQuery ->
radarChartData =
  labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Partying", "Running"]
  datasets: [
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)"
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff"
    data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
  ,
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)"
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)"
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)"
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff"
    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
  ]

myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("radar_graph").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData,
  scaleShowLabels: false
  pointLabelFontSize: 10
)
```

But now the chart doesn't render and I am not sure why. The canvas is still in the HTML view file.

Comment: Is that your real indentation in the CoffeeScript?

Comment: Yes it is - I just started learning coffee script today :) - I guess indentation matters...

Comment: You want to indent everything below `jQuery ->` one level. What you have now is `jQuery(function() { })` followed by a bunch of stuff that runs before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Wow! - thank you - That fixed my problem - I never could have guessed that on my own.